# What is the meaning of Sequestered germline?

Tags: genetics

What is the meaning of Sequestered germline. I understand the meaning of Sequestered in English but what is its meaning in context of germline.

For eg-"  female germ cells are Sequestered early in development ".

Answer (score 1):

"The germ line cells are sequestered" means "the germ line cells are separated from the non-germ line (somatic) cells."